Alternating Directions of My Gaze
Looking east, I see 5 things:
a smiling black man with a heart o'love
Looking south, I see 5 things:
a section marked between Joan Jett's band, then a smiling black man
What food am I thinking of?
Hint: (Added 11-27-2024)

 The title is a great hint, especially the first word of it!

Hint: (Added 11-28-2024)

 ... and especially the first 3 letters of the first word of it!

Big Hints: (Added 11-29-2024)

 Keeping it simple, this puzzle uses the original 3-digit OEM alt codes, as displayed here.To make the divisions of 5 more explicit, here are the clues re-written in a helpful way:[a smiling black] [man] with a [heart] [o]'[love]and[a section mark]ed between [Joan Jett's band], then [a smiling black] [man]


V unir n farnxvat fhfcvpvba lbh'er Uhatnevna.

@msh210 lol. No, I am not. The food is very American.

It might be we will have to see…I think people are apprehensive to upvote it atm because of aesthetic reasons - it doesn’t look like a good puzzle. But they say not to judge a book by its cover so…

Partial answers welcome, but whoever gets the final step- the food- gets the check mark.

Ha! With the second hint, I'm pretty sure that this here is relevant. I don't know what the food is, though, except maybe number 35. And why five things?

@MOehm haha you found it too, been stuck on how to find the food item. Food emojis also have alt codes btw…

Five could be their names BLACK SMILING FACE, HEART SUIT?

@Jlee I think this would have been nigh impossible without the second hint

@PDT the near-impossible ones CAN BE the most satisfying in the end, but you've gotta stick with it. The shortness of it means you don't lose much time thinking about fluff, dead-end clues or red herrings. Alt codes for food emojis are not the correct path..

I don't have enough for even a partial answer, but there's always enough for some speculative rambling: rot13(Gur svir guvatf ner yrggref, rnpu ercerfragrq ol n pbageby punenpgre va gur QBF pbqrcntr: n urneg vf P, n frpgvba znex vf H, gur fzvyvat oynpx zna vf O be creuncf rira OX. Rnfg naq fbhgu pbhyq or gur evtug-snpvat gevn C naq gur qbja neebj L. Gur pbageby pbqrf nyfb unir anzrf, fb gung guvf, gung vf n fcnqrf flzoby, pbhyq or n cneg bs "oynpx".)

rot13(V'z guvaxvat znlor pyhr 1 vf sbe n oynpx fzvyrl snpr, naq pyhr gjb vf sbe n oebxra urneg, orpnhfr wbna wrgg'f onaq vf hfhnyyl ercerfragrq ol n urneg.)

You're thinking of

 corn

After the big hint,

 "a smiling black" is ☻, code 2
 "man" is ♂, code 11
 "heart", "love", and "Joan Jett's band" are all ♥, code 3
 "o" is o, code 111
 "a section mark" is §, code 21

Noticing that all of those are

 small-digit (base-10) numbers, and there are 5 of each, and thinking of the "looking east/south" as giving the clues along the edges, we suspect they are clues to a Nonogram puzzle.  Some tiny cryptic crossword thinking (and failing to get a workable Nonogram otherwise, and having only four of the promised five parts) for "between" gives the puzzle:
 
playable link

whose solution is

 
 splitting the grid with three rows on top and two columns on left, alternating positive/negative color schemes as we read left-to-right and top-to-bottom, this is CORN!


@JLee Swapping, I'd go for rot13(ghexrl)?  But I thought of those directions as very clear; that's how I think of the clues for similar puzzles, rot13(gur ahzoref fnlvat jung lbh frr jura lbh ybbx va gung qverpgvba).

both sequences of numbers are correct, and your realization that the low numbers means it is a small nonogram is correct. but you have the "East" numbers running north to south (down), and the "South" numbers running west to east (to the right). I assume you accidentally flipped them?

Like I said, not accidentally, I was thinking of me "looking east" and seeing the shaded cells of the nonogram, and put the corresponding numbers running up and down.  Anyway, I see your version of it now.  I've got to run for a few, but I'll swap the puzzle in a while.

Ah, well done! JLee, when you stand in the northeast corner, you see the numbers looking east and south as you intended, but the numbers themselves are stacked in the other direction.

Yes of course, northwest corner. Lost my bearings there.

Turkey? How'd you get that?

@JLee lol, I'm not great at the pixel art around here.  I thought the upper-right blob as a head, the lower-left as its wattle.

The 3 puzzle downvoters are the ones who cannot see corn in that solution. Lol  I also suspect that the use of the word "black" (in the puzzle) to describe a man might be taken as racist, as ridiculous as that is.
